# jQuery Input Trigger Live Change

Tags: jquery, input, triggers, live

I am successful in executing a change when I click on a radio button, but the problem is, when I reload the page, the radio button selections are retained, but the change is not. In other words, if I click radio button #1, it will lower the opacity of certain fields. When I come back to this page, all the fields have full opacity, and it is not until I click on the radio button again that it will execute the chance.

Here is my code:

```
(function($) {

    // Document Ready
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // trigger change on the radio list to show selected field
        $('#acf-feature_slide ul.radio_list li label input').trigger('change');

    });

    // Content Type change
    $('#acf-feature_slide ul.radio_list li label input').live('change', function() {

        // vars
        var value = $(this).val();

        // show the selected field
        if( value == "internal" ) {
            $(this).parentsUntil('tr').find('div.row-layout-field').eq(3).css('opacity', '1.0');
            $(this).parentsUntil('tr').find('div.row-layout-field').eq(4).css('opacity', '0.2');
        }
        else if( value == "external" ) {
            $(this).parentsUntil('tr').find('div.row-layout-field').eq(3).css('opacity', '0.2');
            $(this).parentsUntil('tr').find('div.row-layout-field').eq(4).css('opacity', '1.0');
        }
        else if( value == "none" ) {
            $(this).parentsUntil('tr').find('div.row-layout-field').eq(3).css('opacity', '0.2');
            $(this).parentsUntil('tr').find('div.row-layout-field').eq(4).css('opacity', '0.2');
        }
        else {
            $(this).parentsUntil('tr').find('div.row-layout-field').eq(3).css('opacity', '1.0');
            $(this).parentsUntil('tr').find('div.row-layout-field').eq(4).css('opacity', '1.0');
        }

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Consider using `on` as `live` became deprecated in jQuery v1.7. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: In which way do you reload the page? Is it a "quick refresh" (usual hotkey `F5`) or do you also clean the cache along with it (`shift + F5`). While developing I recommend the latter one.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers will retain what choice you picked for certain buttons upon reload (it's *NOT GUARANTEED* to always work or to work on every browser), but will definitely not retain things like triggered events. In other words, you need to store your radio button choice AND your opacity choice in 1 of 2 ways (or both) so they persist on reload 1.) HTML5 localStorage (don't recommend using cookies for this) 2) server side.

Your current code does not store anything - you just got lucky in your case that your browser happened to keep your radio button choice upon reload.

**EDIT:** So you didn't get lucky with the radio buttons...very nice! If you can be sure the radio button stays checked upon reload, then yes, you can verify to see if it is checked.

Let's say you know exactly the id of the radio button you want to verify - and you want to know if its checked or not. Do this on your document load: $('#myradiobutton').is(':checked'); Will return false if not checked, and true if it is checked. Then you can use if statement to say

```
if( $('#myradiobutton').is(':checked') ){
   dothis();
}
```

Comment: I should clarify that I am using this in the Wordpress backend, using the ACF plugin. Radio button choices will always be retained. Is there any way for me to, upon load, check to see what the value is of a radio button and set the opacity, while still allowing a live trigger change?

Comment: Oh definitely. Pretend you know exactly your radio button you want to verify - and you want to know if its checked or not. Do this on your document load: $('#myradiobutton').is(':checked'); Will return false if not checked, and true if it is checked. Hope this helps!